# Validating Dynamically generated field arrays in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, validation, jquery

i have a form where some fields are dynamically generated.

```
<table class="insideform">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#addrange').click(function(){
                                            var value = '<tr><td><input type="number" size="10" id="from" name="from[]" value=""></td>';
                                                value += '<td><input type="text" size="10" id="to" name="to[]" value=""></td>';
                                                value += '<td><input type="text" id="disprice" name="disprice[]" /></td>';
                                                value += '<td valign="middle" id="removerange">x</td>';
                                                value += '<td id="to_err" class="err"></td></tr>';

                                            $('.discounttable').append(value);
                                        });

                                        $('body').on("click","#removerange",function(){
                                            $(this).parent().remove();
                                        });

                                        $('#maxqty').change(function(){
                                            var value = $('#maxqty').val() + " Above";
                                            $('#maxabove').text(value);
                                        });

                                    });
                                </script>
                                    <table class="discounttable">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>From</th>
                                            <th>To</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="right"><span id="maxabove">10 Above</span></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="maxaboveinput" id="maxaboveinput" /></td>
                                            <td id="maxaboveinput_err" class="err"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="text" size="10" id="from" name="from[]" value=""></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" size="10" id="to" name="to[]" value=""></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" /></td>
                                            <td valign="middle" id="removerange">x</td>
                                            <td id="to_err" class="err"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> <input type="button" name="addrange" id="addrange" value="Add Row"/>
```

i want to validate all the to[], from[] fields in codeignitor,
i use ajax call to validate the form here is the code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        console.log($("#form").serialize());
        $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/placeorder/valids',
                type:'POST',
                data:$("#form").serialize()
                }).done(function(data){
                    $("#validations").html(data);});
```

i tried to write this code in the controller:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 $this->form_validation->set_message('%s required', '*required');



 $this->form_validation->set_rules('to[]', 'To field', 'required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('from[]', 'From field', 'required|xss_clean');

 $errors = array();

 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo validation_errors();

    }
```

it doesnt validate my fields... and validation_errors doesnt show any thing i tried to parse it to json and echo the json code... the 'to' and 'from' shows empty in json.
can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Sample controller :

```
  public function sample_controller() {

    if ($this->input->post()) {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('from[]', 'From field', 'required|xss_clean');
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        echo 'success';
      } else {
        echo validation_errors();
      }
    }
    $this->load->view('sample_view');
  }
```

Sample view :

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" size="10" id="from" name="from[]" value="dino"/>
  <input type="text" size="10" id="from" name="from[]" value="babu"/>
  <input type="text" size="10" id="from" name="from[]" value="kannampuzha"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

// Output

1) if any text box is empty

```
The From field field is required.
```

2) if all text boxes filled

```
success
```